# post object state machine

Tags: uml, state, diagram, state-machine

I'd like to model a `Post` object from a social networking app and avoid the combinatorial explosion of states. For example, I could have a superstate `published` which would have as substates `commented`, `liked`, `reported`, etc. The problem is that a published post can be `commented and liked`, `commented and liked and reported`, etc. and I didn't want to create these artificial combined states. Nesting them is also not a good solution as there is no order or hierarchy between any of these substates and it would eventually lead to the combinatorial increase problem. Orthogonal regions don't seem a solution either. Any clues?

Comment: Why Orthogonal regions don't seem a solution? Yes, they do! Provide more detailed description what are the possible states and how are they related to each other.

Comment: @Ister Yes, you're right.  It's more like a pet peeve of mine with orthogonal regions: "if you catch yourself using orthogonal regions, slap yourself" ;-) Or, to put it more politely - as Jim L. suggested below - maybe you better rethink you problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need states for this at all, unless you need to restrict possible events or have different behaviors for an event. Does having a comment or a "like" on a post really change anything you can do to the post?

Usually, orthogonal states that explode in complexity indicate you need to more accurately reflect the things in the problem domain, and each of those classes needs its own separate state machine.

What you probably need is a state machine for a comment (e.g., added, edited, deleted), a state machine for a "like" (e.g., added, retracted, reinstated), and so on.